# Powershell does not create CSV if there is no data to export in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to export VM data from Azure and below script is working perfect if subscription has VMs however it does create a .csv if there is no data (VMs) and I need that even if there is no data powershell should create a blank csv. Below is my script which is working fine if subscription has VMs created in it.

```
function create($path) {
    $exists = Test-Path -path $path
    Write-Host "tried the following path: $path, it" $(If ($exists) {"Exists"} Else {"Does not Exist!"}) 
    if (!($exists)) { New-Item $path -itemType Directory }
}

# reading file contents 
$subs_file =  "C:\Scrpting\Subscriptions\Subscriptions.xlsx"
$azSubs = Import-Excel $subs_file
$azSubs
$output_folder = "C:\audit-automation"
# creating folder for outputing data 
create("$output_folder")
# New-Item $output_folder -itemType Directory

# iterating over subscriptions 
ForEach ( $sub in $azSubs ) {
    # sub
    $azsub = $sub.Subscription
    # app
    $app = $sub.Application
    $azsub
    $app
    # creating folder to save data for apps  
    # New-Item $output_folder\$app -itemType Directory
    # setting config for azure 
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $azsub
        # GET VM INFO
    $vms = Get-AzVM
    $vmrg = Get-AzVM | Select-Object "ResourceGroupName"
    $nics = get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null }
    # creating folder to save 
    # New-Item $output_folder\$app\vm_info -itemType Directory
    create("$output_folder\$app")
    ForEach ($nic in $nics) {
        $info = "" | Select VMName, ResourceGroupName, OS, PrivateIPAddress, PublicIPAddress, SubscriptionID, Status, NICName
        $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id
        $info.NICName = $nic.Name
        $info.VMName = $vm.Name
        $info.SubscriptionID = $azsub
        $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
        $info.PrivateIPAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
        $PublicIPAddress =
        (Az vm list-ip-addresses --name $vm.Name --resource-group $vm.ResourceGroupName | ConvertFrom-Json).virtualMachine.network.publicIpAddresses.ipaddress
        $info.PublicIPAddress = if ($null -eq $PublicIPAddress ) { "Not Assigned" } else { $PublicIPAddress }
        $info.OS = $vm.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        $info.Status = ((Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status).Statuses[1]).code
        $info | Export-Csv -Path $output_folder\$app\$app-vm_data$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).csv -Append
    }}
```

Comment: Please **indent** your code properly so it becomes visible where a scriptblock starts and ends.

Comment: Corrected the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the function `create` and replace that with just the one line `$null = New-Item $output_folder -ItemType Directory -Force`.
On file system, the `-Force` makes the cmdlet return either the DirectoryInfo object of an existing folder or create a new folder and return that.
(don't use this on registry keys!)

Next, if you capture the output you want in the CSV file first, it is easy enough to check if there is output or not and if not, write an empty csv file (only the headers will be in there)

Something like this:

```
# reading file contents 
$subs_file = "C:\Scrpting\Subscriptions\Subscriptions.xlsx"
$azSubs    = Import-Excel $subs_file
#$azSubs
$output_folder = "C:\audit-automation"
# creating folder for outputing data 
$null = New-Item $output_folder -ItemType Directory -Force

# iterating over subscriptions 
foreach($sub in $azSubs) {
    # sub
    $azsub = $sub.Subscription
    # app
    $app = $sub.Application
    $azsub
    $app

    # setting config for azure 
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $azsub
    # GET VM INFO
    $vms  = Get-AzVM
    $vmrg = Get-AzVM | Select-Object "ResourceGroupName"
    $nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $null -ne $_.VirtualMachine }
    # creating folder to save 
    $null = New-Item (Join-Path -Path $output_folder -ChildPath $app) -ItemType Directory -Force

    # capture the output of the foreach loop
    $result = foreach ($nic in $nics) { 
        $info = "" | Select VMName, ResourceGroupName, OS, PrivateIPAddress, PublicIPAddress, SubscriptionID, Status, NICName
        $vm   = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id
        $info.NICName = $nic.Name
        $info.VMName  = $vm.Name
        $info.SubscriptionID    = $azsub
        $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
        $info.PrivateIPAddress  = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
        $PublicIPAddress = (Az vm list-ip-addresses --name $vm.Name --resource-group $vm.ResourceGroupName | 
                            ConvertFrom-Json).virtualMachine.network.publicIpAddresses.ipaddress
        $info.PublicIPAddress = if ($null -eq $PublicIPAddress ) { "Not Assigned" } else { $PublicIPAddress }
        $info.OS     = $vm.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        $info.Status = ((Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status).Statuses[1]).code
        # output the object to be collected in variable $result
        $info
    }
    # test if you actually have data now in the $result variable
    if (!@($result.Count)) {
        # no data; create an empty csv with just the headers
        $result = "" | Select VMName, ResourceGroupName, OS, PrivateIPAddress, PublicIPAddress, SubscriptionID, Status, NICName
    }
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $output_folder -ChildPath ('{0}\{0}-vm_data{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.csv' -f $app, (Get-Date))
    $result | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Hi @Theo,

Thank you for the script, I will try this script and let you know. 

Also I will need subfolders under Output folder because these will be application folders to which the subsciption belongs to. There will be more than 25 applications and for each application I will pull these reports and upload to SharePoint for audit purpose.

Comment: @Saurabh Ok, I have re-entered the line to create the extra subfolder

Answer (score 0):

add outside the loop, since $vms may be empty

```
if (!($vms)){
    $info = "" | Select VMName, ResourceGroupName, OS, PrivateIPAddress, PublicIPAddress, SubscriptionID, Status, NICName
    $info | Export-Csv -Path $output_folder\$app\$app-vm_data$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).csv -Append
```

}

Comment: Did not work Its not creating the file. I did following changes. @rinat

`$info.Status = ((Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status).Statuses[1]).code}
        if (!($vms)){
        $info = "" | Select VMName, ResourceGroupName, OS, PrivateIPAddress, PublicIPAddress, SubscriptionID, Status, NICName
        $info | Export-Csv -Path $output_folder\$app\$app-vm_data$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).csv -Append
    }}`

Comment: @Saurabh
You have a lot of {}} that mean you are doing this in a loop. If $azSubs or $nics is empty, then everything in the loop will not be executed, including the creation of csv.

Comment: This is part of long script which exports UserRoles and Firewall Rules as well. For firewall rules it works fine even if there are no rules configured.  I am sure that azSubs is not empty as CSV created for firewall rules and UserRoles have data in it.